# Loading Addressables and using ContinueWith()

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a reason why `Task.ContinueWith()` never gets called when loading addressables?

```
Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite>(spriteName).Task.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    spriteRenderer.sprite = task.Result; // never called
});
```

I realize you can use the `Completed` event.

```
Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite>(spriteName).Completed += (op =>
{
    spriteRenderer.sprite = op.Result; // called
});
```

I'm just curious why this is.

Comment: Pretty sure you can only access `spriteRenderer.sprite` from main thread, so the `ContinueWith` might actually be your problem here. Try assigning a string value or something simple in there instead to check, it probably is running, but failing silently on another thread.

Comment: @JNSTabletop usually if it gets called in a different thread Unity would complain about it .. but you're right maybe this is not the case for assigning values. Simply try a `Debug.Log`. since this is a method call Unity will complain if the issue is a different thread.

Comment: @JNSTabletop looks like you're right, assigning a simple string works, but changing anything Unity specific does nothing. Breaking with debugger makes it clear: `*** can only be called from the main thread.`. Guess we're sticking with the `Completed` event.

Comment: @derHugo Interestingly it appears that `Debug.Log` is a thread-safe method. It is called.

Comment: @Iggy interesting .. some time ago I had huge issues logging from other threads ^^ maybe this was changed in latest versions?

Comment: @derHugo Oh maybe, it could also be the silent nature of thread failing. When I try logging `op.Result` I get no errors, but all subsequent `Debug.Log`s stop working, as I assume the whole thing failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Unity Engine API is not thread-safe.

`ContinueWith` is running on a different thread, so assigning a `sprite` to a `SpriteRenderer` from a different thread is invalid.